# Shiny - CSS Stylesheet is shown on app when loading

Tags: css, r, shiny

I included a CSS stylsheet in the UI of my shiny app using the includeCSS function. the stylesheet is saved in the www directory. Please see the code below.

However, when I run the app, it is the first thing that pops up (see screenshot).

I guess it is just a minor glitch somewhere but would be amazing if anyone knew what to do about it.

Happy Holidays!

```
h1 { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 23.4px; color: #8b0000; background-color: #FFCCCB; } 
h3 { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 15.4px;} 
p { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; } 

blockquote { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 21px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 30px; } 

pre { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18.5714px; }

body{
padding-top: 70px;
}
```

[image: screenshot of the viewer when app is deployed]

Comment: As you did not include your code, it is hard to verify your issue.  Perhaps you should try `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),` where custom.css should be renamed to your css file name.

Comment: hi, thanks a ton for getting back! Just figured it out - it was due to the sequencing of my elements in the UI! I had the CSS as second line of code before my content. putting it in last made it disappear when I deployed it.. lol